# Capture output from ssh-add launched by another command

Tags: bash, stdout, ssh-agent

Here's the full version of my question. I'm including all this detail in case my hunch is wrong, but you may want to skip to the tl;dr below.

I'm trying to write a function that runs an arbitrary command and also captures whether any output was printed to the terminal. I don't want to interfere with the output being printed. In case it's a relevant complication (probably not), I *also* want to branch on the exit code of the command.

Here's what I have:

```
function run_and_inspect {
    # this subshell ensures the stdout of ${@} is printed and captured
    if output=$(
        set -o pipefail
        "${@}" | tee /dev/tty
    ); then
        did_cmd_work="yes"
    else
        did_cmd_work="no"
    fi

    if [ -z "$output" ]; then
        was_there_output="no"
    else
        was_there_output="yes"
    fi

    echo "output?" $was_there_output
}
```

Generally this works fine:

```
$ run_and_inspect true
output? no

$ run_and_inspect "echo hello"
hello
output? yes
```

But I've found one problem command:

```
git pull | grep -v 'Already up to date.'
```

If there is nothing to pull, this pipeline usually produces no output. But, if ssh-add needs to prompt for a passphrase, there *is* output. It just doesn't get noticed by `run_and_inspect`:

```
function git_pull_quiet {
    git pull | grep -v 'Already up to date.'
}

$ run_and_inspect git_pull_quiet
Enter passphrase for key '/home/foo/.ssh/id_ed25519':
output? no
```

There *was* output to my terminal. I assume the problem is it didn't come from stdout of the `git pull` pipeline, which is all `run_and_inspect` knows about. Where did it come from? How do I fix this? I've tried redirecting stderr too (i.e. `git pull 2>&1`), but with no luck. Is there some way to monitor /dev/tty directly?

### tl;dr (I think!)

I *think* this question boils down to: why isn't the passphrase prompt in log.txt?

```
$ git pull 2>&1 | tee log.txt
Enter passphrase for key '/home/foo/.ssh/id_ed25519':
Already up to date.
$ cat log.txt
Already up to date.
```

Comment: git must print that message to stderr, try `git pull 2>&1 | tee log.txt`

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work. I mentioned that I'd tried that in the question, but I've made it more obvious now.

Comment: So `git pull` writes to `/dev/tty` directly. And?

Comment: I want to capture all output that appeared in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

> why isn't the passphrase prompt in log.txt?

The prompt is printed from [openssh load_identify_file](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/39be3dc209f28f9c1ebfeba42adde8963b01e1cd/sshconnect2.c#L1533) with [readpass.c read_passphrase()](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/add926dd1bbe3c4db06e27cab8ab0f9a3d00a0c2/readpass.c#L123). The function does `open(_PATH_TTY` with [_PATH_TTY "/dev/tty"](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/48d0d7a4dd31154c4208ec39029d60646192f978/defines.h#L478) and then `write()`s to it.

The output is displayed directly to the terminal `/dev/tty`, not with standard streams.

Just like you do with your `tee /dev/tty`, which means that your function will also not work. Prefer to preserve the stdout-ness of the child program and preserve buffering:

```
if { tmp=$("$@" > >(tee >(cat >&3))); } 3>&1; then
```

> Is there some way to monitor /dev/tty directly?

Write your own terminal emulator and spawn your process in it, and then parse all input inside that terminal emulator. Programs like `screen` or `tmux` may be of use.

The workaround could be to download `proot` and open a file descriptor to some file, then create a chroot with just `/dev/tty` file symlinked to `/proc/self/fd/<that file descriptor>` and run the process with `proot` inside that chroot. The idea is that process will see that chroot with `/dev/tty` file replaced and will write to your file descriptor instead to the terminal.